# How to make read only custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I create custom post type named as "Booking". I want to make this post type read only means "Add New" and "edit" option should not display in back end.
This post type is not related with plugin.This is simple custom post type to display booking details.Here is my code..

```
function demotheme_register_post_types() {    

    //custom posttype booking
    $booking_labels = array(
                                'name'               => _x( 'Bookings', 'demotheme_booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'singular_name'      => _x( 'Booking', 'demotheme_booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'menu_name'          => _x( 'Bookings', 'demotheme_booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Bookings', 'demotheme_booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'demotheme_booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'new_item'           => __( 'New Booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'view_item'          => __( 'View Booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'all_items'          => __( 'All Bookings', 'demotheme' ),
                                'search_items'       => __( 'Search Booking', 'demotheme' ),
                                'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Booking:', 'demotheme' ),
                                'not_found'          => __( 'No bookings found.', 'demotheme' ),
                                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No bookings found in Trash.', 'demotheme' ),
                            );

    $booking_args = array(
                            'labels'             => $booking_labels,
                            'public'             => true,
                            'publicly_queryable' => true,
                            'show_ui'            => true,
                            'show_in_menu'       => true,
                            'query_var'          => true,
                            'rewrite'            => false,
                            'capability_type'    => 'post',
                            'capabilities'       => array('read_post'=>'read_demotheme_booking'),
                            'map_meta_cap'       => true,
                            'has_archive'        => true,
                            'hierarchical'       => false,
                            'menu_position'      => null,
                            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' )
                        );

    register_post_type( DEMOTHEME_BOOKING_POST_TYPE, $booking_args );


    //flush rewrite rules
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

//add action to create custom post type
add_action( 'init', 'demotheme_register_post_types' );
```

At back end side, i want view booking/all booking option only. Publish or update button should not display.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a plugin to manage your user role for this task. I like this one [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).

FYI, whatever capabilities you add onto your CPT, that's what will show in the list of capabilities in the User Role Editor.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i want to make only one CPT read only, not all.
Plugin which is suggested by you is based on user role. I think these settings will affect all post types. Plugin gives functionality for different capabilities. but this is not working for me

Comment: I still think this plugin is what you are looking for, if I understood you correctly. A user Admin will always be able to create, publish, edit and delete a CPT, otherewise there is no way to manage the CPT, correct? If you want a read-only to that specific CPT, then you need a different user-type, say for example, 'reader', and within the User Role Editor you set that user-type to read-only to that specific CPT. By setting 'map_meta_cap' to true, you get the basic capabilities with it. I don't think you can get only the read capability; that has to be defined by user role.